# How do I set up a nested-has-many-through relationship for accessing deeply nested data on the grandfather model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have a raffle, raffle tickets, and people who buy tickets. What I want to do is (from the raffle), see who all has bought tickets.

In short: Raffle has-many tickets. Tickets have-many Buyers.

How do I achieve this sort of proxy / aggregate / flattening of a has many of a has many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of tricky, as you need to be specify the source class and both the source association depending on which port of the relationship you are setting up.

See:

```
class Raffle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :raffle_tickets,
    class_name: LineItem::RaffleTicket.name,
    foreign_key: 'reference_id'

  has_many :ticket_purchasers,
    class_name: Buyer.name,
    through: :raffle_tickets,
    source: :purchasers
end

class LineItem::RaffleTicket < LineItem
  belongs_to :raffle, foreign_key: :reference_id

  # has_many :buyer_line_items # defined in LineItem
  has_many :purchasers,
    through: :buyer_line_items,
    source: :buyer
end

class BuyerLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer
  belongs_to :line_item # polymorphic
end
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
purchasers = Raffle.first.ticket_purchasers
purchasers.map(&:class)
=> [Buyer, Buyer, Buyer, etc...]
```

The above is the equivalent of defining the following method on the raffle model:

```
def ticket_purchasers
  raffle_tickets.map(&:purchasers).flatten
end
```